# effects of sunlight through a glass window?

Tags: radiation

Both my father and my grandfather where drivers, and over time ended up with a wrinklier left hand compared to the right hand, due to sunlight exposure over 40+ years while holding the steering wheel with the left hand. I googled for sunlight exposure through a glass window and I get contradictory answers either stating either that most glasses filter out UV-light that affects skin tanning and ageing or that the effect of sunlight on skin is pretty much the same if it is direct or through a glass window.
So, are the effects of sunlight through a glass window different from direct sunlight exposure?

Comment: This question has more of a *Physics* bent to it than Biology. UVB/UVA light will cause burning/aging, that much is known. You're talking about how light interacts with a medium, and why it does so. That said, I seem to remember reading that tinted/filtered windows do protect you - but regular glass offers no protection at all since it's not designed to disrupt the light in any way.

Comment: Wikipedia says that glass blocks ninety percent of light below 300nm.

Comment: @AlecS even if it is only 10% the hours of driving and the latitude would play a large role. One hour radiation in the equator is ten hours or so  close to the poles. And infrared cooks the skin after all, and that passes the glass.

Answer (score 1):

There are papers that provide a starting point for further research:

- M. Moehrle, M. Soballa, M. Korn: *UV exposure in cars.* In: *Photodermatology, photoimmunology & photomedicine.* 19(4) August 2003, pp. 175–181. [PMID 12925188](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12925188)
- M. G. Kimlin, A. V. Parisi: *Ultraviolet radiation penetrating vehicle glass: a field based comparative study.* In: *Physics in medicine and biology.* 44(4) April 1999, pp. 917–926. PMID 10232805. [PMID 10232805](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10232805)
- M. G. Kimlin, A. V. Parisi, B. D. Carter, D. Turnbull: *Comparison of the solar spectral ultraviolet irradiance in motor vehicles with windows in an open and closed position.* In: *International journal of biometeorology.* 46(3), August 2002, pp.150–156. PMID 12194009

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as a proper answer

Comment: Why not? This is academic literature that yahoo301503 might be unaware of and that covers the topic "sunlight through vehicle windows".

Comment: I don't doubt that the answer lies within that literature but normally answers explain the solution and support it with literature